# how to getUiSettings() in MAPBOX V10 Java

Tags: mapbox, compass

guess it is simple yet I cannot achieve it. I want to get the UiSettings for Mapbox

In build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.10.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-scalebar:10.10.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-compass:10.10.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-logo:10.10.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.plugin:maps-core:10.10.0'
```

in Activity onStart()

```
    mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onStart();

    mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.OUTDOORS);
    mapView.getMapboxMap().setNorthOrientation(NorthOrientation.UPWARDS);
    mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(new CameraOptions.Builder()
            .center(Point.fromLngLat(11.0, 52.0))
            .zoom(15.5)
            .build());
```

I can bring up the mapView, use the new easeTo methods etc. to update the camera yet I am unable to get the **UiSettings** as in (earlier versions) with **.getUiSettings**.

(I am also struggling with modifying the **Scalebar** and bringing up the compass. Obviously I am not understanding how to use these features in **Mapbox v10**.)

Thanks for your time and help. This is my first post, hoping it comes out well :-)

Best,
Thomas

failing

```
mapView.getMapboxMap().getUiSettings()
```

```
ScaleBarSettings ss = new ScaleBarSettings();
ss.setEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late but maybe also for others spending their time with the v10 update: From Java you can use the these utils classes provided by Mapbox :

```
LogoUtils.getLogo(mapView).setEnabled(false);
AttributionPluginImplKt.getAttribution(mapView).setEnabled(false);
GesturesUtils.getGestures(mapView).getSettings().setPinchToZoomEnabled(true);
```

and so on. Regarding the scalebar I did not find a Java soluton. You can write a Kotlin helper class like

```
class KotlinUtil {

    companion object{

        fun hideScalebar(mapView: MapView){

            mapView.scalebar.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

and use it from java

```
KotlinUtil.Companion.hideScalebar(mapView);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Not well documented by Mapbox since their switch to Kotlin. Add this one to the list as well if you need to access the compass:
CompassViewPluginKt.getCompass(mapView).setEnabled(true);